# C# I have a list of <Person>objects in a dataGridView. How can this be searched by a user inputing text into a txt box input?

Tags: c#, list, object, datagridview, bindinglist

I have a list of `Person` objects that contain the variables `{int id, string name, string status, int age}`. How can this be searched by a user inputting text into a text box?

I have the list of `Person` in a binding list attached to a `dataGridView`.  I would like to search the `dataGridView` for a person's name or age, or any of the variables and to return a list of all the rows that contain information found.  This is what I have now.

```cs
BindingList<Person> foundPerson = new BindingList<Person>();
bool found = false;
if (txt_PeopleSearch.Text != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < foundPerson.Count; i++)
    {
        if 
        (foundPerson[i].ToString().ToUpper().Contains
        (txt_PeopleSearch.Text.ToUpper()))
        {
            foundPerson.Add(foundPerson[i]);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (found)
    {
        dgvPerson.DataSource = foundPart;
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No People match your search");
        dgvPerson.DataSource = foundPerson;
    }
}
```

Comment: "foundPart" not declared

Comment: is this code correct ? You have declared foundPerson and then started searching on this object without adding any data in this collection.  Where is foundPart? Instead of for loop you can use lambda expression.

Comment: please show PERSON class deatils

Comment: Keep your Persons in a datatable instead; life will be much easier. If you're willing to make a switch, let me know and I'll write an answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try following code avoid loop use lambda expression.

```
BindingList<Person> foundPerson = new BindingList<Person>();

foundPerson.Where(x => x.age.ToUpper() == txt_PeopleSearch.Text.ToUpper() ||
 x.status.ToUpper() == txt_PeopleSearch.Text.ToUpper() || x.name.ToUpper() == 
 txt_PeopleSearch.Text.ToUpper()).ToList();
  if(foundPerson.Count>0)
     {
       dgvPerson.DataSource = foundPerson;
     }
     else
     {
       MessageBox.Show("No People match your search");
       dgvPerson.DataSource = foundPerson;
     }
```